# Should Vibration Feeback work on the softscreen on HTC Desire HD phone

Tags: htc-desire-hd, haptic-feedback

I think this used to work on my phone and then stopped. Vibration feedback is enabled but only works for the four off screen buttons - Home , Menu, Back, & Search not for any icons on the home or other screens.

So how can I get it to work normally again?

Comment: Did you install a custom ROM? Besides I can confirm that the HTC Desire HD does have full screen vibrate, so there must be something else going on

Answer (score 1):

As long as the phone has a vibrator (and you mention it does), then it should work, unless HTC modified their flavour of the Android software.

Go to 'settings'-> 'Language & keyboard' -> your keyboard (often 'Android keyboard' or 'Touch input') -> enable 'Vibrate when typing' (in case of 'Touch input' this is in a 'Text input' submenu).

The real 'vibrate' (on call)  function as you know it from your old feature phone is at 'settings' -> 'Sound' -> 'Vibrate'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an HTC Desire - but on my HTC EVO in the sound settings there is an option to turn on "Haptic Feedback". (Settings, Sound, under 'Feedback' - I'm guessing since they are both HTC they will be similar)

Its says:

> Vibrate when pressing soft keys and *certain* UI interactions

*Edit: emphasis mine*

if this is the setting that you have enabled then I think the functionality you are describing is correct since my phone only vibrates on soft keys and certain things like moving icons or widgets on the home screen.  Clicking icons doesn't vibrate.